# Force Laravel to use HTTPS version

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https, pagination

I have a laravel site and I'm trying to get everything to work on with SSL.
Though it seems that Laravel wants to use http instead.
For example I was using the `form` element and the method was automatically sending to http. The same thing using the built in `style`, `script` links which I changed all to work statically (regular ol' HTML). The last thing which I can't manage to figure out is the pagination (using jscroll).
I have this row:

```
{!! $plugins->appends(['tag' => $param2, 'search' => $param1 ])->render() !!}
```

Which prints this:

```
    <ul class="pager">
<li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li> 
<li class="jscroll-next-parent" style="display: none;"><a href="http://siteurl.net/pagename/page/?tag=XXX&amp;search=&amp;page=2" rel="next">»</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how I change that to be https?
Thanks!

Comment: You may consider redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS via htaccess (if you're using apache) as well.

Comment: Make sure your APP_URL= in your .env has https:// in-front.

Comment: That won't help since the URL that prints on the screen is http, I need to change what gets printed

Comment: I actually didn't have APP_URL but I added it and it didn't change anything

Comment: did u find proper solution?

Answer (score 21):

Try this, go to AppServiceProvider place this code in the boot method:

```
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

The class:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Other way is enforce by .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Remember about clearing cache in browser (then htaccess will work correctly).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, though I get an error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::forceScheme()

Any way how to fix this?

Comment: Try import: use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

Comment: laravel version?

Comment: I got it! use: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route (i just edited answer)

Comment: version: 5.0.31. I got so excited I thought it was going to work. But no. Got the same error

Comment: Unfortunately htaccess isn't good enough since I'm using ajax here and it's mixed content and gets blocked. I did find however that previous versions are called forceSchema with an A at the end. This isn't producing an error but it doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Why would .htaccess not work for ajax requests?  Are you requesting https:// in your ajax?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate https routes only (but still plain http requests allowed), change AppServiceProvider:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

if you want to redirect any http request to https, add a global middleware:

```
class ForceHttpsMiddleware{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){

        if (!$request->secure() && App::environment() === 'production') {//optionally disable for localhost development
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got everything to work by enforcing SSL on Couldflare. It's not in the code but it works.

Comment: so htaccess in other words

Answer (score 0):

forceScheme is wrong it should be forceSchema, you should find AppServiceProvider and under the boot function add:

```
\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

It means it will be

```
public function boot()
{
    \URL::forceSchema('https');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

open `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

add below class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

then just write below source in **`Boot()`** function of AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

if($this->app->environment('production')) { // it will force redirect to https in Production mode 
      URL::forceScheme('https');
}

?>
```

it will force redirect **http request to https**

& then update `APP_URL` variable with https url in `.env file`

for ex:-

```
APP_URL=https://stackoverflow.com
```

If you use this way then you does not required to any change in server file or .htaccess file

> **Note:- I use Laravel 8 So, I am not sure it will works in below Version of Laravel 8**